# How to eliminate multiple server calls | MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

There is a stored procedure that needs to be modified to eliminate a call to another server.

What is the easiest and feasible way to do this so that the final SP's execution time is faster and also preference to solutions which do not involve much change to the application?

Eg:

```
select * 
from dbo.table1 a 
inner join server2.dbo.table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: It looks like this stored procedure depends on a join to a table on another server, how do you expect to remove this join and get the expected results? The only option I see is having server2 write table2's data to the server which hosts table1 and then join those tables so that you have no need for a linked server join.

Comment: You could [replicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) the table on server2 so it's available on your original server. This requires minimal modifications to both the application and stored procedure, but obviously the replication needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Cross server JOINs can be problematic as the optimiser doesn't always pick the most effective solution, which may even result in the entire remote table being dragged over your network to be queried for a single row.

Replication is by far the best option, if you can justify it.  This will mean you need to have a primary key on the table you want to replicate, which seems a reasonable constraint (ha!), but might become an issue with a third-party system.

if the remote table is small then it might be better to take a temporary local copy, e.g. `SELECT * INTO #temp FROM server2.<database>.dbo.table2;`.  Then you can change your query to something like this: `select * from dbo.table1 a inner join #temp b on a.id = b.id;`.  The temporary table will be marked for garbage collection when your session ends, so no need to tidy up after yourself.

If the table is larger then you might want to do the above, but also add an index to your temporary table, e.g. `CREATE INDEX ix$temp ON #temp (id);`.  Note that if you use a named index then you will have issues if you run the same procedure twice simultaneously, as the index name won't be unique.  This isn't a problem if the execution is always in series.

If you have a small number of ids that you want to include then `OPENQUERY` might be the way to go, e.g. `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('server2', 'SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id IN (''1'', ''2'')');`.  The advantage here is that you are now running the query on the remote server, so it's more likely to use a more efficient query plan.

The bottom line is that if you expect to be able to JOIN a remote and local table then you will always have some level of uncertainty; even if the query runs well one day, it might suddenly decide to run a LOT slower the following day.  Small things, like adding a single row of data to the remote table, can completely change the way the query is executed.

Comment: Also sometimes it's good enough to "replicate" the table by scheduling a job to copy it over the linked server connection on a schedule.

Comment: Agreed, and this is one solution I use on a daily basis.  The downside here is that sometimes the job fails, and also there's an inherent latency being introduced, also locking issues if you want to query the table when it's being refreshed.  However, it's a very effective solution for reporting if these problems aren't breaking.